# Youtube video pausing in every 2 or 3 seconds

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I am developing an application which will play video from youtube using YouTubePlayerView. But video is going to pause mode in every two or 3 seconds.This is the layout i am using

```
 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and my activity code where loading video is

```
 @Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                    boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo("My video id");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using YoutubeFrgment instead of YoutubePlayer:

```
<fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

The point is - your Activity has to extend activity from youtube sdk, if you want to use YoutubePlayer inside layout, maybe this is the problem. See example project from sdk.
And you also MUST not put anything above youtube view

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `player.cueVideo("My video id");` try  the following

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    mPlayer = player;

    if (!wasRestored) {

        player.loadVideo(youtubeId);

    }
}
```

This code was working perfectly for me !!!!